# Assistance with calculation and rounding to 2 decimal places

Tags: java, android

I have an activity which adds up prices with amount of orders, and with an option to add vat on top of that too. The ex vat price is fine, always adds to 2 decimal places. However when adding vat (20% for uk) it ends up being more than 2 decimal places. I have seen other suggestions and haven't been able to get it working. any help would be greatly appreciated. My code is as follows

```
        editText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    editText2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    editText3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
    editText4 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText4);
    editText5 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText5);
    editText6 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText6);
    editText7 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText7);
    editText8 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText8);
    editText9 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText9);
    editText10 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText10);
    editText11 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText11);
    editText12 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText12);
    editText13 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText13);
    editText14 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText14);
    editText15 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText15);
    editText16 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText16);
    editText17 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText17);
    editText18 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText18);
    editText19 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText19);
    button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);

    button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (editText19.getText() != null || editText18.getText() != null || editText17.getText() != null || editText16.getText() != null || editText15.getText() != null || editText14.getText() != null || editText13.getText() != null || editText12.getText() != null || editText11.getText() != null || editText10.getText() != null || editText9.getText() != null || editText8.getText() != null || editText7.getText() != null || editText6.getText() != null || editText5.getText() != null || editText4.getText() != null || editText3.getText() != null)
                editText2.setText((String.valueOf(11.67 * (Double.parseDouble(editText16.getText().toString())) + ((15.83 * (Double.parseDouble(editText17.getText().toString())) + ((18.33 * (Double.parseDouble(editText18.getText().toString())) + ((18.33 * (Double.parseDouble(editText18.getText().toString())) + ((24.17 * (Double.parseDouble(editText19.getText().toString())) + ((22.36 * (Double.parseDouble(editText15.getText().toString())) + ((4.17 * (Double.parseDouble(editText14.getText().toString())) + ((26.66 * (Double.parseDouble(editText13.getText().toString())) + ((4.17 * (Double.parseDouble(editText12.getText().toString())) + ((30.96 * (Double.parseDouble(editText11.getText().toString())) + ((4.17 * (Double.parseDouble(editText10.getText().toString())) + ((35.26 * (Double.parseDouble(editText9.getText().toString())) + ((4.17 * (Double.parseDouble(editText8.getText().toString())) + ((39.56 * (Double.parseDouble(editText7.getText().toString())) + ((4.17 * (Double.parseDouble(editText6.getText().toString())) + ((9.17 * (Double.parseDouble(editText5.getText().toString())) + ((13.33 * (Double.parseDouble(editText4.getText().toString())) + ((17.20 * (Double.parseDouble(editText3.getText().toString())))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))));


    ;};;});

    button2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (editText19.getText() != null || editText18.getText() != null || editText17.getText() != null || editText16.getText() != null || editText15.getText() != null || editText14.getText() != null || editText13.getText() != null || editText12.getText() != null || editText11.getText() != null || editText10.getText() != null || editText9.getText() != null || editText8.getText() != null || editText7.getText() != null || editText6.getText() != null || editText5.getText() != null || editText4.getText() != null || editText3.getText() != null)
                editText1.setText((String.valueOf(1.2 * ((11.67 * (Double.parseDouble(editText16.getText().toString())) + ((15.83 * (Double.parseDouble(editText17.getText().toString())) + ((18.33 * (Double.parseDouble(editText18.getText().toString())) + ((18.33 * (Double.parseDouble(editText18.getText().toString())) + ((24.17 * (Double.parseDouble(editText19.getText().toString())) + ((22.36 * (Double.parseDouble(editText15.getText().toString())) + ((4.17 * (Double.parseDouble(editText14.getText().toString())) + ((26.66 * (Double.parseDouble(editText13.getText().toString())) + ((4.17 * (Double.parseDouble(editText12.getText().toString())) + ((30.96 * (Double.parseDouble(editText11.getText().toString())) + ((4.17 * (Double.parseDouble(editText10.getText().toString())) + ((35.26 * (Double.parseDouble(editText9.getText().toString())) + ((4.17 * (Double.parseDouble(editText8.getText().toString())) + ((39.56 * (Double.parseDouble(editText7.getText().toString())) + ((4.17 * (Double.parseDouble(editText6.getText().toString())) + ((9.17 * (Double.parseDouble(editText5.getText().toString())) + ((13.33 * (Double.parseDouble(editText4.getText().toString())) + ((17.20 * (Double.parseDouble(editText3.getText().toString())))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))));
            ;};;});



}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually I use a BigDecimal to scale a decimal value and display it to user. Let's do this for editText1 :

```
button2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
                if (editText19.getText() != null || editText18.getText() != null || editText17.getText() != null || editText16.getText() != null || editText15.getText() != null || editText14.getText() != null || editText13.getText() != null || editText12.getText() != null || editText11.getText() != null || editText10.getText() != null || editText9.getText() != null || editText8.getText() != null || editText7.getText() != null || editText6.getText() != null || editText5.getText() != null || editText4.getText() != null || editText3.getText() != null) {
                    // Create a big decimal with your value
                    BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(1.2 * ((11.67 * (Double.parseDouble(editText16.getText().toString())) + ((15.83 * (Double.parseDouble(editText17.getText().toString())) + ((18.33 * (Double.parseDouble(editText18.getText().toString())) + ((18.33 * (Double.parseDouble(editText18.getText().toString())) + ((24.17 * (Double.parseDouble(editText19.getText().toString())) + ((22.36 * (Double.parseDouble(editText15.getText().toString())) + ((4.17 * (Double.parseDouble(editText14.getText().toString())) + ((26.66 * (Double.parseDouble(editText13.getText().toString())) + ((4.17 * (Double.parseDouble(editText12.getText().toString())) + ((30.96 * (Double.parseDouble(editText11.getText().toString())) + ((4.17 * (Double.parseDouble(editText10.getText().toString())) + ((35.26 * (Double.parseDouble(editText9.getText().toString())) + ((4.17 * (Double.parseDouble(editText8.getText().toString())) + ((39.56 * (Double.parseDouble(editText7.getText().toString())) + ((4.17 * (Double.parseDouble(editText6.getText().toString())) + ((9.17 * (Double.parseDouble(editText5.getText().toString())) + ((13.33 * (Double.parseDouble(editText4.getText().toString())) + ((17.20 * (Double.parseDouble(editText3.getText().toString())))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))));
                    // Round value to 2 decimal
                    bd = bd.setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
                    editText1.setText(bd.toString());
                 }
            }
        });
```

Comment: this throws up a few errors. BigDecimal before bd wants a ; to complete which I find weird. It also gives me a few quick fixes, usualy with creating a field for BigDecimal.

Comment: Sorry a bracket was missing after the if

Comment: You sir, are a LEG-END, muchos gracias senor

Comment: I like the end of the line -> .toString())))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))));

Answer (score 0):

I see 2 possibilities :

```
String.format("%.2f", yourValue);
```

It'll round your string to a 2 decimal.

Or else,

- multiply by 100
- round to integer value (or ceil or floor)
- divide by 100 again to float

Comment: it'll take "yourValue" and display it correctly, so for me AFTER the calculation. But yourValue will still have all the digits, only the string displaying will be with 2 digits. If the number need to be rounded to 2 digits, use my second proposition.

Comment: +1 ;-) I go for one right now, you can join (BTW isn't java a coffee) doh.

Comment: just thinking. I'm using the calculation to be displayed into a editText, would it be better in a textView?

Comment: It depends on the application ;-) not sure i'll be of any help on that point. EDIT : simply for showing textView is better

Comment: I have changed it to textView, tried your method, couldnt get it to work, and tried @clydealmighty method too. frustrating

Answer (score 0):

i strongly suggest make use of variable,it will make your life easier and

Here's an utility that rounds a double to specified number of decimal places.

For example:

round(123.456, 2);// returns 123.46

Comment: I didn't know about a round method accepting the digits as parameters. Is that a standard java/android library ? I shall test that.

Comment: I have entered it in, tried it before the calculation and after the calculation. And still it doesn't work